# Float left/right a VegaLite text mark

Tags: charts, vega-lite, vega

Does anyone know how we can float right/left a text mark?

To be more specific, in this [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEOy+O0oeJJBDNZUMB1OOaRZQxgaVUN6fyQADxoIQ2U2ZBog4UcFQ0DlQ2SITDgkLIYISPM5ZTpdd0MyTSyoNkE2M0w2ePUkawzDAC84dVaTYtS4SkUVJEwUVFA3DzU0AG1QKZB9MaY0fgAmAA4AXwVltBAAIXW0AFYLg6P0AGFz1H4AZmebkBWAEUeATgBGd4rACijx2AMOH2OADFHhc3hCVgBxR78P4-QHHAASoIA7Bj0ABJWFbPYAXQOIDgsnq5VkZDQoAAngyQAAzGhwQTKY4oJSYRk4ODHWSJZLuMbRWIshJJPSs9zFPk0KAAawgaHlgkVIEESCYnP0dMEQtQAAYlLr9YIAAoFWn01BiPYUqIs9mc7noDZ8gUmkAARwYgR0k2cQqU0HcJtAODtyQdW1NFMl6umIBqoTuDSaLPqsnKOjkLLyuWOygmDAQlFmnkMAF4G4ZTWMa36mLrVSAKa3jgBiZQDrvOim6xl9RagZDqFXHEzqLsQqcztP8wXHPJRTAS4RkPSgOBRHDz9DlzCVyhMQwAHibhgA-IYAOSaMhYR+GVBP42szCPhcqV00wPI8ywrKtLxvU170MbYP0MLYhyUKkaXjYsDy3NN3S5WcxlXP1A2DOgJhoUghzJPYgA) can we float those aligned values to the start/end of the X-axis on each level.

Or, if float is not possible, any method to put a left and a right limit text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEOy+O0oeJJBDNZUMB1OOaRZQxgaVUN6fyQADxoIQ2U2ZBog4UcFQ0DlQ2SITDgkLIYISPM5ZTpdd0MyTSyoNkE2M0w2ePUkawzDAC84dVaTYtS4SkUVJEwUVFA3DzU0AG1QKZB9MaY0fgAmAA4AXwVltBAAIXW0AFYLg6P0AGFz1H4AZmebkBWAEUeATgBGd4rACijx2AMOH2OADFHhc3hCVgBxR78P4-QHHAASoIA7Bj0ABJWFbPYAXQOIDgsnq5VkZDQoAAngyQAAzGhwQTKY4oJSYRk4ODHWSJZLuMbRWIshJJPSs9zFPk0KAAawgaHlgkVIEESCYnP0dMEQtQAAYlLr9YIAAoFWn01BiPYUqIs9mc7noDZ8gUmkAARwYgR0k2cQqU0HcJtAODtyQdW1NFMl6umIBqoTuDSaLPqsnKOjkLLyuWOygmDAQlFmnkMAF4G4ZTWMa36mLrVSAKa3jgBiZQDrvOim6xl9RagZDqFXHEzqLsQqcztP8wXHPJRTALynUtj24twTdujlc2djVd+wPBugTGikbeutPlzCVlmHnDz9DPyuUJiGAA8TaGAA-IY-AXKahioIYfyms2w5knsQA)?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with negative values. We can hide the axis domain line, and instead use a conditional grid color to draw a zero baseline.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": -28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": -33},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": -19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {
        "domain": false,
        "ticks": false,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelPadding": 4
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"padding": 20},
      "axis": {
        "gridColor": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.value === 0", "value": "black"},
          "value": "#ddd"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {"datum": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? -50 : 100"}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This seems oke, I will try it on my own case and see if it's exactly what I need. Many thanks for the time! I will come back with an conclusion :D

Comment: Good stuff. Don't forget to mark as solved for other users.